# Video speed can't be set to 1.5x

Tags: microsoft-teams

I just encountered a bug in microsoft Teams.
When I replay a video and want to change the speed to 1.5x it gets marked but is still played in 1x speed.
 This is also the case for 1.2x and 1.8x. 2x speed still works and 0.5x just stops the video.
I already restarted my computer and reinstalled teams. I couldn't find anything else to this issue on the internet.
How it looks in ms Teams:

[image]

EDIT:

 - Version is 1.3.00.28779 (64-Bit).

 - Stream now works in Firefox and Chrome

 - Same issue still in application, a friend is experiencing the same problem

EDIT:EDIT:

 - Version Version 1.4.00.4167 (64-Bit)

 - The feature to watch recordings in the teams application has been removed.

Comment: Is there a Stream link to the video? If so, does it work OK in the Stream? Which version of Teams? Unable to replicate on 1.3.00.28779 (64 bit)

Comment: Version is 1.3.00.28779 (64-Bit). I have this problem for every video in Teams and I can't open a single one in Stream, when I try I get the 0x20200259 error. I am currently checking my firewall.

Comment: I just tried to open the video in chrome (prviously firefox) and now it works but still the same error in the teams application.